# Behaviour DocsList.getFolder(path) in case identical foldernames

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

The Google Apps Script documentation of Class Folder starts with

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('kittens');
```

Indeed it returns an object referring to folder 'kittens', even if that folder is nested several levels deep.

I asked myself "what happens if several folders 'kittens' exist in the tree of folders"??

I made an example and indeed the same code just returned ONE reference to a folder 'kittens'.

So my conclusion is the code presented is ambiguous and results are unreliable as I don't know what criteria are used for the folder to be returned.

```
var folders = DocsList.getFolder();
```

exists, returning ALL folders, but

```
var folders = DocsList.getFolder('kittens');
```

returning all folders 'kittens' does not exists.

I know you can use

```
var listFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('kittens');
```

but that does return a FolderIterator instead of an array of folders.

Can anybody tell me if I'm missing a point, why did Google not provide a method returning an array of folders and what criteria are used to determine what folder will be returned by `DocsList.getFolder('kittens');`

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. It's better to ask direct questions, so it's possible to get clear answers.

Comment: DocsList returns ONE folder if you call 'DocsList.getFolder('Kittens');' even if SEVERAL folders named 'Kittens' exist. What are the crtiteria for DocsList to choose what folder it will return? Second question is 'why did Google not provide a function to get an array of elements, but just an iterator'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DocsList.getFolder()` is a special method that tries to emulate folder paths on the file system. That is to say it takes a path string and tries to find a folder that matches that path. Since Google Drive allows for multiple folders with the same name, this can be confusing, and we generally don't recommend using it.

As for why `DriveApp.getFoldersByName()` returns an iterator, it's a design decision made when designing the service. All methods that could return a large number of results return an iterator instead of an array for performance reasons.